# Is there a way to query folder sizes of an outlook inbox?

Tags: c#, outlook

I am looking for a way to interact with Outlook 2013 and query the folder sizes of individual folders (similar to the "Folder size" dialog in outlook). This is from the user side and not from the admin side.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the outlook client is using exchange you could use [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220499%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) and then this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568624/how-do-i-get-folder-size-with-exchange-web-services-2010-managed-api)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new Application();
            var ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            ns.Logon();
            var inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            var size = inbox.Items.OfType<dynamic>().Sum(s=>s.Size);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Darek, how do these methods help? :)

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev StorageItem has `Size` property

Comment: Returns an integer indicating the size (in bytes) of the StorageItem. How is it related to Inbox?

Comment: Can you imagine querying all items in a folder and summarizing their sizes? I'd like to believe it will give you the correct folder size. If not, i.e. hidden items, you could use `GetTable` on the folder.

Comment: I see the answer suggested to use the GetStorage and StoreageItem which doesn't have anything common with the Inbox size.

Comment: Do not use LINQ with Outlook objects - it will keep al collection items referenced until the loop terminates. If you are using an online Exchange store, you will run out of RPC channels resulting in an exception. There is no reason to open each and every item in the folder  - use MAPIFoldder.GetTable and request Size property. You can then request all rows and sum up their values.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for that.

You may try to count the [Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861257.aspx) of each item in the folder (including hidden items).

Comment: What hidden items - like these? https://www.msoutlook.info/question/58 ?