# How to get outlook mailbox space using python exchangelib

Tags: python, exchangelib

My company is using Microsoft Exchange server 2016. Each mailbox only has 1G space allocated. How can I get the mailbox usage information using python exchangelib?

I am using Python 3.9.5 with exchangelib 4.4. I can use exchangelib to send and receive email however, cannot find the right way to get the mailbox space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS does not provide a direct API for this, but it seems you can get the folder size using extended properties. See e.g. [How do I get folder size with Exchange Web Services 2010 Managed API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568624/how-do-i-get-folder-size-with-exchange-web-services-2010-managed-api)

exchangelib does support extended properties. See https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#extended-properties